# Product page load without main product image, but server return error 500

Tags: product, http-error-500

My product pages are loading fine, but almost 2 or 3 products load photos without the main product image, the rest of the page load fine but using debug tools the browser report error 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check in your /pub/media/catalog/product folder images are exist or not.
2. Check folder permission.
3. Run commands:
         php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
         php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Image exist, and I cant see any error in front end, I've added the correct permissions, I was checking the logs and I found some warnings. I removed and it works now, the problem wasn't the images.